# Remove extra curly braces

Tags: braces, arguments

In this MWE, I demonstrate my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\newcommand{\dosomething}[1]{\uppercase{#1}}
\newcommand{\dosomethingelse}[1]{\seqsplit{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \dosomething{looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong}

    % works with extra {...}
    \dosomething{{looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong}}

    \dosomethingelse{looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong}

    % does not work with extra {...}
    \dosomethingelse{{looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong}}
\end{document}
```

Some commands work with extra curly braces, some don't. Why is that, and how can  I make them work by preprocessing my arguments when they do have extra curly braces?

Comment: If you remove the `{...}` in `\dosomethingelse` around `{#1}` it works with the doubled `{...}` as well.

Comment: But then the use case without extra `{...}` (example 3) will stop working... (it still compiles, but it stops doing what it should, which is breaking the line).

Comment: In my point of view, the excess `{....}` forms a group that can't be used by the `seqsplit` command in order to split it

Comment: I agree. Is there a way to *ungroup* this group?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the argument is not empty and starting spaces can be removed, then the following trick helps:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dosomethingelse}[1]{%
  \expandafter\seqsplit\expandafter{\@firstofone#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

`\@firstofone` is defined in the LaTeX kernel as:

```
\long\def\@firstofone#1{#1}
```

It grabs the first token as argument and outputs it again, thus it does "nothing".
But if the argument is not a single token, but a token group in braces, then one level of braces are removed.

Comment: Thanks! Can one make this a standalone command such as `\removeBraces[1]` or so? Then one could call `\seqsplit{\removeBraces{#1}}` - I don't seem able to put this together.

Comment: @bers `\seqsplit` scans the argument without expanding it. When `\removeBraces` is called, it's already too late.The answer uses `\expandafter` to expand `\@firstofone` (requires one expansion step exactly), before `\seqsplit` scans it argument.

Answer (score 2):

It mostly depend on *what* command you're dealing with.

If you have `\textit{{xyz}}`, the additional braces just add a level of grouping; for `\seqsplit` it's a completely different ballgame, because this command scans its argument one item at a time and a braced group is a single item.

This is described in the manual of `seqsplit`, in section 2.3:

> **2.3 Grouping and Commands**
>
> The command `\seqsplit` does not insert breakpoints between the letters inside braces `{...}`.
>
> [...(*omitted example*)...]
>
> The braces around `{kahg}` prevented a splitting of this group. This effect can be used for typesetting special substrings inside sequences.

Braces have a very important syntactical meaning and should not be used in a casual way.