# Remove extra curly braces for def'ed argument

Tags: expansion, grouping

I am trying to combine the answers of [Remove extra curly braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/300865/30810) and [\def'ed plain-text argument behaves differently from plain text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301262/30810), and I am failing. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\newcommand{\dosomething}[1]{\expandafter\seqsplit\expandafter{\@firstofone#1}}

\begin{document}
    \def\kong{looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong}
    \def\kongg{\kong}
    \def\konggg{{looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong}}

    % works
    \dosomething{looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong}

    % works, too
    \expandafter\dosomething{\expandafter\kong}

    % works with extra {...}
    \dosomething{{looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong}}

    % works with extra {...}, too
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\dosomething{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\kongg}

    % does not work
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\dosomething{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\konggg}
\end{document}
```

For the larger picture, this is what I am getting at:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref}

%1 \usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{showlabels,xpatch,seqsplit}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\SL@margintext}{\{\SL@prlabelname{#1}\}}{#1}{}{err}
\patchcmd{\maketag@@@}{{\df@label}}{{\expandafter\df@label}}{}{err}

\patchcmd{\showlabelsetlabel}{#1}{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\parbox{1.5\marginparwidth}{\scriptsize\vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}\seqsplit{#1}}}}{}{err}

%2 \renewcommand{\showlabelsetlabel}[1]{\meaning\df@label}

%4 \newcommand{\dosomethingelse}[1]{\expandafter\seqsplit\expandafter{\@firstofone#1}}
%4 \patchcmd{\showlabelsetlabel}{\seqsplit}{\dosomethingelse}{}{err}

\begin{document}

    %3 \patchcmd{\label@in@display@noarg}{{{#1}}}{{#1}}{}{err}

    \section{A}
    \label{sec:Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong}

    \begin{equation}
    \label{eqn:Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong}
        X = Y
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This code behaves well until I load `cleveref` (uncomment `%1`). You will see why after uncommenting `%2`: `\df@label`, set by `amsmath`'s `\label@in@display`, has an extra layer of `{...}`.

`cleveref`, on the other hand, seems to be the one introducing this:

```
\def\label@in@display@noarg#1{\cref@old@label@in@display{{#1}}}%
\def\label@in@display@optarg[#1]#2{%
  \cref@old@label@in@display{[#1]{#2}}}%
```

And it seems to depend on it, as you can see when you try to `xpatch` it out (uncomment `%3`). So instead of that, I tried to remove the curly braces as before (**comment** `%2`, uncomment `%4`), to no avail.

Comment: You're are loading 4 packages that change the way `\label` works usually -- there must be interferences ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am not surprised, but this doesn't mean I don't want to be able to manage these interferences ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem with your code isn't the definition of `\dosomething` but your test cases. Let's have a look at how the expansion goes in your test cases:

1. ```
   \dosomething{looong}
   \expandafter\seqsplit\expandafter{\@firstofone looong}
   \seqsplit{looong}
   ```
2. ```
   \expandafter\dosomething{\expandafter\kong}
   \dosomething{\expandafter\kong}
   \expandafter\seqsplit\expandafter{\@firstofone\expandafter\kong}
   \seqsplit{\expandafter\kong}
   ```

   Here you can see that the `\expandafter`s are not properly applied, as one goes into the parameter of `\seqsplit` which probably is not what you intended. It still seems to work accidentally because of how `\seqsplit` works internally.
3. ```
   \dosomething{{looong}}
   \expandafter\seqsplit\expandafter{\@firstofone{looong}}
   \seqsplit{looong}
   ```
4. ```
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\dosomething{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\kongg}
   \expandafter\dosomething{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\kongg}
   \dosomething{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\kongg}
   \expandafter\seqsplit\expandafter{\@firstofone\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\kongg}
   \seqsplit{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\kongg}
   ```

   Again, here `\expandafter`s find its way into `\seqsplit`'s parameter.
5. ```
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\dosomething{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\konggg}
   \expandafter\dosomething{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\konggg}
   \dosomething{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\konggg}
   ```

   The same problem here, which prevents the `\@firstofone` trick to apply.

On the other hand, if you put `expandafter`s in the right dose, the result is correct with all of your three `\kong` macros:

```
\expandafter\dosomething\expandafter{\kong}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\dosomething\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\kongg}

\expandafter\dosomething\expandafter{\konggg}
```

[image]

Comment: "I think the problem with your code isn't the definition of \dosomething but your test cases" - exactly, I should have mentioned that!

Answer (score 2):

The workaround is simpler.

First of all, don't add big code in `\patchcmd`, it becomes difficult to maintain. Second, using a macro allows us to define a slicker behavior.

So I change `#1` in the code for `\showlabelsetlabel` with `\massage@label{#1}`.

This is defined to do `\massage@@label#1\@nil`, which will remove an outer pair of braces from the argument, by rule: braces are removed from a delimited argument so long as this doesn't leave unmatched braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{showlabels,xpatch,seqsplit}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\SL@margintext}
  {\{\SL@prlabelname{#1}\}}
  {#1}
  {}{err}

\patchcmd{\showlabelsetlabel}
  {#1}
  {\massage@label{#1}}
  {}{err}

\newcommand{\massage@label}[1]{\expandafter\massage@@label#1\@nil}
\def\massage@@label#1\@nil{%
  \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \parbox{1.5\marginparwidth}{%
      \scriptsize\vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}%
      \expandafter\seqsplit\expandafter{#1}
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

    \section{A}
    \label{sec:Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong}

    \begin{equation}
    \label{eqn:Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong}
        X = Y
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]